# How can I convert Oracle 12g encoding from AL32UTF8 to WE8ISO8859P15?

Tags: oracle, encoding

I'm looking for ways to convert my DB from AL32UTF8 to WE8ISO8859P15. First of all I'd like to ask if this is possible? I've seen that CSSCAN and CSALTER are no longer supported in 12c. If it is possible, where can I find some kind of manual on how this is done.

Thank you for the help!
al.

Comment: Any particular reason you'd want to restrict it like that?

Comment: The database of my clients is in WE8ISO8859P15 and it can't be changed. I would like to have the same encoding on my dev/test system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not a production environment the easiest way is to create a new database with the correct encoding and export, import from AL32UTF8 database into the new one.

Comment: You mean that is not possible to do it with some Oracle tool? I've read that WE8ISO8859P15 is single-byte and AL32UTF8 is 4-byte. Is this the reason why this can't be achieved without reinstalling the DB?